Inserting rows of Tiberius select query results into Hashmap<String, String>
I am using the tiberius crate for T-SQL queries in Rust.
use tiberius::{Client, Config, AuthMethod};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio_util::compat::TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt;
use anyhow::{ Result, Error };
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error>{

    // create connection client and set up connection config
    let mut config = Config::new();
    config.host("my_server");
    config.port(1433);

    // use windows trusted authentication to connect
    config.authentication(AuthMethod::Integrated);
    config.trust_cert();

    // create a tcp stream using our configuration
    let tcp: TcpStream = TcpStream::connect(config.get_addr()).await?;
    tcp.set_nodelay(true)?;

    // create a SQL client
    let mut client = Client::connect(config, tcp.compat_write()).await?;
    let results = client.query("SELECT 'hello' AS foo, 'world' AS bar;", &[])
        .await?
        .into_results()
        .await?;

    let mut map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    for i in &results[0] {
        let foo: String = i.get("foo").unwrap().to_string();
        let bar: String = i.get("bar").unwrap().to_string();
        map.insert(
            foo,
            bar,
        );
    }

    Ok(())
}

I am basically running a oneshot query and want to read the values into a HashMap<String, String>.
I receive the following error in the get() call:
32 |         let foo: String = i.get("foo").unwrap().to_string();
   |                             ^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `R` declared on the method `get`

Based on the docs, I am not sure I understand why I am receiving this error. The data in SQL Server should be represented as a &str or String.
An additional error says that the trait FromSql<'_> is not implemented for std::string::String but in the documentation it says that this is already implemented.

I guess remove .to_string() and he should guess the right type

Please post the full error from cargo check. You've truncated it.

I've reopened this question since while the proposed duplicate can provide an answer to an expert, it may be very hard for a beginner to realize how it answers the question.

Can you explain which of .get::<String> and .get::<&str> or .get::<LiterallyAnyImplToString> Rust should pick and why? If you can't then why do you expect Rust can.
